# Multiple values in a column for a single value in another column display

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to display multiple rows of a column linked to a single value in another column in ORACLE.
But I am not even close and not sure what to use to achieve that.

Suppose my table and query is recuperating the below :

| node_no | code |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | AB |
| 100 | FG |
| 100 | ef |
| 101 | dc |
| 101 | TT |

What I am trying to achieve, is a display as below:

| node_no | code |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | AB |
|  | FG |
|  | ef |
| 101 | dc |
|  | TT |

where the value in node_no is not repeated when having multiple values code related, but still keeping the display on several rows. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It's possible in the query (though you'd need to include sample data and your current query for us to really tell you how). But this seems like something the application/report/etc. should be doing; SQL\*Plus can do this for instance.

Comment: Sorry I am asking for a query in Sql dev to check if this is feasible. Given a query like SELECT * FROM NODE_S ORDER BY NODE_NO DESC ... I am checking if this type of display is feasible

Comment: If you're running as a script you can just do `break on node_no nodup`. But is that what you mean; or are you running as a statement with the output in the query result grid?

Comment: I am running a statement

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Alex Poole's very good suggstion, You can achieve the same using analytical function -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEAD_node_no = node_no THEN NULL ELSE node_no END node_no, code
  FROM (SELECT LEAD(node_no) OVER(PARTITION BY node_no) LEAD_node_no, node_no, code
          FROM YOUR_TABLE);
```

From your example it doesn't seems you need an ordered result. If you need so, You have to use Order by clause in LEAD function.

Comment: I am getting   Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query

Comment: @mikeb, Please try now.